# Drawing an arrow with specified direction on a point in scatter plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, scatter

Is there a way to draw a scatter plot in Julia (preferably with gr backend), in which every point has an arrow pointing to a specified direction on it?

Specifically, my task is to create a gif image with multiple moving points with a small arrow on every point pointing to the direction of its velocity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, you want to plot a vector field, right?

The "arrow plot" you are looking for, is usually called `quiver`-plot in many programming languages. In Julia, too.

If you use `Plots.jl` the syntax is `quiver(x,y,quiver=(u,v))`, where `x` and `y` are the coordinate vectors and `u` and `v` the arrow magnitude vectors.

If you use `GR` or `PyPlot` directly the syntax is possibly a bit different.

#### Small Example

```
using Plots
gr()
N = 10
x = rand(1:10,N)
y = rand(1:10,N)
u = rand(N)
v = rand(N)
scatter(x,y)
quiver!(x,y,quiver=(u,v))
```

[image: quiver plot example]